# Error during running : char at memory place

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have an error I don't understand. When I execute my code I got that:

> Exception non gérée à 0x00007FF9CC11A799 dans perception.exe : exception Microsoft C++ : char à l'emplacement de mémoire 0x000000ACEC0FE568. a eu lieu

That can be transleted in English by

> Uncatched exception at XXXXX in perception.exe : Exception Microsoft C++ : char at memory place YYYYY happened

I got the error here:

```
void NaiveBayesianNetwork::trainModel(mat& X, vec& y)
{
    // Initial checks
    if (X.n_cols != m_numFeatures)
        throw "The dimension of 'X' data is not consistent with number of features";
    if (X.n_rows != y.n_rows)
        throw "Dimension of 'X' and 'y' are not consistent";

    y = trunc(y); // only integer
    cout << "max " << y.max() << " ; min " << y.min() << endl;
    if (y.max() >= m_numClasses)
        throw "The number of classes in 'y' is bigger than expected";
    if (y.min() < 0.0)
        throw "The class ids should be positive";
    m_numberOfSample = X.n_rows;
//...
```

on the line `if (y.min() < 0.0)`, but if I comment it, I got the error after. So it's not a matter of the function (it works in the previous print). `mat` and `vec` are Armadillo library objects, they are crated in `main` that call the function. I printed them and they are looking good.

If I try to catch exception here, I still got the debuger error, and no exception is catch.

I really don't understand the problem, because I'm not using pointer (at first I wasn't even using references, but I got the same problem. I added reference to avoid useless copy), so I don't know why there is a memory problem. The debugger is talikng about `Kernel.dll`, I don't know if it's useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're throwing exceptions in this code. Do you `catch` them somewhere?

Comment: It's worth putting this into your debugger to see what state your code is in when it crashes. Step through the code and see where it breaks.

Comment: You are throwing strings - are you trying to catch strings? (Also, tell me more about `y`. What is a `vec`?)

Comment: First of all, the "exception" you're getting is not a C++ exception, but a hardware exception which is different and can't be caught. Secondly, how do you call this function? What `mat` and `vec`? What are `x` and `y` referencing? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: On another couple of notes, please don't `throw` string literals, create suitable exception classes (preferably based [the standard exception categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error#Exception_categories)). Also only use exceptions for this that really are exceptional, not as simple user-input validation (for example).

Comment: There's really not enough information here to solve the problem. You should learn how to use a debugger, so you can solve it for yourself. If I was debugging this code the first thing I would be looking at is `y = trunc(y);` but this is only a hunch.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nothing wrong with exceptions for validation. From the program's perspective, invalid input _is_ exceptional. Besides, people get too hung up on the English meaning of "exceptional" here; the dictionary shouldn't be in charge of good program design.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Unlike many other languages with exceptions, in C++ a thrown exception can be rather expensive, especially if there's a deep call-stack before the specific exception is caught. And by throwing an exception for input validation you effectively push the validation up the call-stack, perhaps to functions where it could break the single-responsibility principle.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course you only push the validation up to a function whose responsibility is already appropriately to handle such things. Also exceptions really aren't _that_ expensive any more, especially compared to the cost of I/O...

Comment: Hello, thanks to @Someprogrammerdude remark, I changed my `throw` to a real exception instead of `string` (I wanted to be fast), and it corrected the problem!

Comment: For others questions, I catch my exception in the `main` function, where I call the `trainModel` function.
For the content of X and y, I checked them and it was correct, as well as trunc function that did the job. As I said, `mat` and `vec` come from Armadillo library and are matrix and vectors.
Also, I didn't about the problem that exception can produce, I'll check about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested me @Someprogrammerdude in comments, the problem was the `throw`. I should replace the `string` by a proper `exception`, that solved my problem.

Because, my program was throwing an exception during the execution (I could see it after changing the string).

Thanks.